# Hash table library implementation

Tags: c, linked-list, hash-map

I wrote my own implementation of generic hash table. I’m using linked list to resolve collision problem.
I want to share my code with you and get your opinion about it, and if there are any advice or optimisations that you can point to.

HashTable.h file

```
/**
 * @author      Abdelhakim RAFIK
 * @version     v1.0.1
 * @license     MIT License
 * @Copyright   Copyright (c) 2021 Abdelhakim RAFIK
 * @date        Feb 2021
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* hash table node definition */
typedef struct _node
{
    unsigned char *key;
    void *value;
    struct _node *next;
} ht_node_t;

/* hash table definition */
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int count;
    ht_node_t **items;
} ht_table_t;


/**
 * create new hash table with given size
 * @param  size     items table size
 * @return          pointer to creates hash table
 */
ht_table_t* ht_create(int size);

/**
 * create items table index from given key
 * @param  key      key value
 * @return          index of items table between 0 and table size-1
 */
unsigned int ht_hash(unsigned int maxSize, unsigned char *key);

/**
 * inset new element to hash table by given key
 * @param  table    pointer to created hash table
 * @param  key      key for value to insert
 * @param  value    element to be inserted
 * @param  size     size of element in bytes
 * @return          1: inserted successfully
 *                  0: error occured while inserting value
 */
unsigned char ht_insert(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key, void *value, size_t size);

/**
 * find associated node to given key
 * @param  table    pointer to hash table
 * @param  key      key associated to the node
 * @param  index    index of found node in items table
 * @param  prev     pointer to previous node
 * @return          node pointer if found or NULL otherwise
 */
ht_node_t* ht_find_node(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key, unsigned int *index, ht_node_t **prev);

/**
 * find value in hash table by given key
 * @param table     pointer to hash table
 * @param key       key of the value searching
 */
void* ht_find(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key);

/**
 * delete value by given key
 * @param  table    pointer to hash table
 * @param  key      value's key to delete
 * @return          1: deleted successfully
 *                  0: error occured while deleting the value
 */
unsigned char ht_delete(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key);

/**
 * delete all table items
 * @param table     pointer to hash table
 */
unsigned char ht_delete_all(ht_table_t* table);

/**
 * free allocated memory for given hash table
 * @param  table    pointer to hash table
 */
unsigned char ht_free(ht_table_t* table);
```

HashTable.c file

```
/**
 * @author      Abdelhakim RAFIK
 * @version     v1.0.1
 * @license     MIT License
 * @Copyright   Copyright (c) 2021 Abdelhakim RAFIK
 * @date        Feb 2021
 */

#include "hashTable.h"

/**
 * create new hash table with given size
 * @param  size     items table size
 * @return          pointer to creates hash table
 */
ht_table_t* ht_create(int size)
{
    // check given table items size, should be greather than 0
    if(size <= 0) return NULL;
    // create new hash table
    ht_table_t* table = (ht_table_t*) malloc(sizeof(ht_table_t));
    table->size = size;
    table->count = 0;
    // create items table as pointer's table to nodes
    table->items = (ht_node_t**) malloc(size * sizeof(ht_node_t*));

    // set all items pointers to NULL
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        table->items[i] = NULL;

    // return created table
    return table;
}

/**
 * create items table index from given key
 * @param  key      key value
 * @return          index of items table between 0 and table size-1
 */
unsigned int ht_hash(unsigned int maxSize, unsigned char *key)
{
    unsigned int hashedKey = 0;
    // create hash from key
    for(; *key != '\0'; ++key)
        hashedKey = (hashedKey * 19 + *key) % maxSize;
    // return created index
    return hashedKey;
}

/**
 * inset new element to hash table by given key
 * @param  table    pointer to created hash table
 * @param  key      key for value to insert
 * @param  value    element to be inserted
 * @param  size     size of element in bytes
 * @return          1: inserted successfully
 *                  0: error occured while inserting value
 */
unsigned char ht_insert(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key, void *value, size_t size)
{
    // check table and key are not NULL
    if(!table || !key) return 0;
    // index from key
    unsigned int index;
    // check whether the element with associated key already in table and get generated index
    ht_node_t *newNode = ht_find_node(table, key, &index, NULL);
    if(newNode)
    {
        // reallocate memory for new content value
        newNode->value = (void*) realloc(newNode->value, size);
        // copy value to allocated node value memory
        memcpy(newNode->value, value, size);
    }
    else
    {
        // create new node
        newNode = (ht_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(ht_node_t));
        // create node key and copy it's value
        newNode->key = (char*) malloc(strlen(key) + 1);
        strcpy(newNode->key, key);
        // create node value memory
        newNode->value = (void*) malloc(size);
        // copy value to allocated node value memory
        memcpy(newNode->value, value, size);
        // if index position is not empty link nodes
        if(table->items[index] != NULL)
            newNode->next = table->items[index];
        else
            newNode->next = NULL;
        // add created node to items table
        table->items[index] = newNode;
        // increment table count
        ++table->count;
    }
    return 1;
}

/**
 * find associated node to given key
 * @param  table    pointer to hash table
 * @param  key      key associated to the node
 * @param  index    index of found node in items table
 * @param  prev     pointer to previous node
 * @return          node pointer if found or NULL otherwise
 */
ht_node_t* ht_find_node(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key, unsigned int *index, ht_node_t **prev)
{
    // get index for given key
    unsigned int _index = ht_hash(table->size, key);
    if(index)
        *index = _index;
    // get head items at index position
    ht_node_t* currentNode = table->items[_index];
    ht_node_t* _prev = NULL;
    // search in linked array nodes until a NULL pointer
    while(currentNode)
    {
        if(strcmp(currentNode->key, key) == 0)
            break;
        // go to next linked node
        _prev = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

    if(currentNode)
    {
        if(prev)
            *prev = _prev;
        // return found node
        return currentNode;
    }
    // value associated with the key not found
    return NULL;
}

/**
 * find value in hash table by given key
 * @param table     pointer to hash table
 * @param key       key of the value searching
 */
void* ht_find(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key)
{
    // check table and key are not NULL
    if(!table || !key) return NULL;

    // get associated node to key
    ht_node_t *currentNode = ht_find_node(table, key, NULL, NULL);
    // node not found
    if(!currentNode) return NULL;
    // return node's value
    return currentNode->value;
}

/**
 * delete value by given key
 * @param  table    pointer to hash table
 * @param  key      value's key to delete
 * @return          1: deleted successfully
 *                  0: error occured while deleting the value
 */
unsigned char ht_delete(ht_table_t* table, unsigned char *key)
{
    // check table and key are not NULL
    if(!table || !key) return 0;

    ht_node_t *prevNode;
    unsigned int index;
    // get associated node to key
    ht_node_t* currentNode = ht_find_node(table, key, &index, &prevNode);
    // node not found
    if(!currentNode) return 0;

    // set previous node next element to current node next element
    if(currentNode->next != NULL)
    {
        if(prevNode != NULL)
            prevNode->next = currentNode->next;
        else
            table->items[index] = currentNode->next;
    }
    else if(prevNode == NULL)
        table->items[index] = NULL;

    // delete node
    free(currentNode->key);
    free(currentNode->value);
    free(currentNode);

    // decrement table count
    --table->count;

    return 1;
}

/**
 * delete all table items
 * @param table     pointer to hash table
 */
unsigned char ht_delete_all(ht_table_t* table)
{
    // check table is not NULL
    if(!table) return 0;

    // delete table items if not empty
    if(table->count != 0)
    {
        ht_node_t *currentNode = NULL, *nextNode = NULL;
        for (int i=0; i<table->size; ++i)
        {
            // get next node
            nextNode = table->items[i];
            while(nextNode)
            {
                currentNode = nextNode;
                nextNode = currentNode->next;
                // free memory allocated by current node
                free(currentNode->key);
                free(currentNode->value);
                free(currentNode);
            }
            table->items[i] = NULL;
        }
        // set table count to 0
        table->count = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * free allocated memory for given hash table
 * @param  table    pointer to hash table
 */
unsigned char ht_free(ht_table_t* table)
{
    // check table is not NULL
    if(!table) return 0;
    // delete table items if not empty
    if(table->count != 0)
        ht_delete_all(table);
    // free table parts
    free(table->items);
    free(table);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: why are you returning `unsigned char`?

Comment: @IrAM to return just a byte of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a lot of thought went into this code.

### License

As someone looking for a hash-table implementation, I would consider a clear MIT license an important point towards your implementation.

### Interface

This is well done, with comments where they are most useful. As a user looking at your interface, I have some questions.

| return | function | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ht_table_t* | ht_create | `int size` should be an unsigned type like `size_t` |
| unsigned int | ht_hash | the hash value should be transparent, return success, (as `int` or `boolean`, depending on the version of C); `maxSize` is undocumented and what is that? (Ed: I see now, this is the hash function; consider a `static` function; it is internal to your implementation.) |
| unsigned char | ht_insert | `int` or `boolean`; don't say what happens on collision |
| ht_node_t* | ht_find_node | how do I deal with a `ht_node_t`? I assume `index` and `prev` are set, but I do not care about the internal representation |
| void* | ht_find | good name, documentation |
| unsigned char | ht_delete | `int` or `boolean` |
| unsigned char | ht_delete_all | what happens to the memory? this causes a compile error; should be `void` |
| unsigned char | ht_free | what does the return mean? |

I suggest a few helper `static` functions, internal to the implementation (private), and have the public functions return less.

### Code

I see "HashTable.h", but in code, it's "hashTable.h". "@Copyright" doesn't fit with the other, lower-case tags. These case-inconsistencies may be bugs.

In `ht_create`, `(ht_table_t*)malloc(sizeof(ht_table_t))` could be `malloc(sizeof *table)`. The cast is confusing, except where you want to port to `C++`, (as you seem to here.) If you want to specify a totally opaque type, then you should declare it in header as something like `struct ht_table_t;` and leave the implementation to the C file. You set all pointers to null appropriately.

You don't check that memory allocations work, so you open yourself up to undefined behaviour; practically, which could be a segfault or something worse if the memory allocation fails. Because the parameter for the requested memory size comes from outside your module, and is something you don't control, I would be especially careful about checking.

`ht_hash` should be private, `static`. A lot of unnecessary work could be saved by taking the remainder outside the loop.

In `ht_insert`, you trust users a lot to take the size accurately, every time.

You accept `unsigned char *key`, but this should be `char *` for consistency, and library functions depend on it.

Three memory allocations, where one will do, slows down your code. However, be very careful about aligning strings.

Comment: "you open yourself up to a segfault" - if _lucky_!  This is Undefined Behaviour, so anything can happen (including _appearing to work_ when under test, then failing catastrophically in real use!).

Comment: @TobySpeight That is a very good point. I've edited my paragraph, thanks.